# How to rewrite the form data key value inside the array [] from angular6 reactive dynamic form

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have created the angular reactive dynamic form in the angular6 project. The forms values I am getting like below:

```
const formValues = {
  name: 'test1',
  age: '02/08/1985',
  product: {
    apple: false,
    orange: true,
    banana: true,
    graps: false
  },
  sex: 'Male',
  city: null,
  address: null
}
```

If the key value is null I will show the empty array if it has value will show the values inside the array and the product key value is true I will show the true values key name only in the product array.
my expected value like this:

```
const formValues = {
  name: ['test1'],
  age: ['02/08/1985'],
  product: ['orange', 'banana'],
  sex: ['Male'],
  city: [],
  address: []
}
```

I tried for loop and map but didn't get the expected result. Please help me out. Thanks

**Note: The form key&values are dynamic so we don't know the exact key name.**

Comment: Do you want to reformat the ```formValues```?

Comment: Yes. I want the reformat the formValues

Comment: Would the ```name``` possible be an object same as ```product``` as well?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the exact output you have in your question. Its a bit concise, so I'll break it out here

```
let fv = formValues, // for brevity, rename the source object
  newFormValues = Object.assign(...Object.keys(fv) // our end result is an object (assign) but we'll loop through using the keys array
     .map(f => ( // for each string from object.keys
         {[f]: fv[f]!==null && typeof fv[f] === 'object' ?  // if the value is not null but is an object (null is also an object but will error if we don't catch it here) ...
             Object.entries(fv[f]).reduce((b,a)=>!!a[1] && [...b,a[0]] || b,[])  :   // return filtered keys from that object (the products for example)
             [fv[f]] // otherwise, just use the value as is, in array format
         })));
```

```js
const formValues = {
  name: 'test1',
  age: '02/08/1985',
  product: {
    apple: false,
    orange: true,
    banana: true,
    graps: false
  },
  sex: 'Male',
  city: null,
  address: null
}
let fv = formValues, newFormValues = Object.assign(...Object.keys(fv).map(f => ({[f]: fv[f]===null ? null : typeof fv[f] === 'object' ?  Object.entries(fv[f]).reduce((b,a)=>!!a[1] && [...b,a[0]] || b,[]) : [fv[f]]})));
console.log(newFormValues)
```

Comment: I think your solution has almost done but the ```city``` should return an empty array instead of ```[null]```.

Comment: @Kinglish The product values will show only the orange, banana which has true values. False value fruits will now show the products array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const formValues = {
  name: 'test1',
  age: '02/08/1985',
  product: {
    apple: false,
    orange: true,
    banana: true,
    graps: false
  },
  sex: 'Male',
  city: null,
  address: null,
}

const getValueByType = (v) => ({
  string: [v],
  boolean: v,
  object: Object.entries({...v}).filter(([_, v]) => v).map(([k, _]) => k),
}[typeof v])

const newFormValues = Object
  .entries(formValues)
  .reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[k] = getValueByType(v), a), {})
  
console.log(newFormValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each property do you want to be an array???

If only you want was an array the "products" you can use

```
formValuesFormatted={...this.formValues,
                        product:Object.keys(this.formValues.product)
                        .filter(x=>this.formValues.product[x])
                    }
```